# How to use PolynomialQ to allow it to accept non-integer exponents?

Tags: polynomials, expression-test

[`PolynomialQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolynomialQ.html) checks if the expression is polynomial in $x$. But this is a mathematical polynomial where exponents can only be integers (or zero).

Is it possible to extend this to accept fractions as exponents also?  i.e. to support $x^{\pm \frac{n}{m}}$ where $n,m$ are integers. This is only for one variable $x$ polynomial, so that

```
specialPolynomialQ[x^2 + x^(3/2) + 3, x]
```

would return `True` also.  Now `PolynomialQ[x^2 + x^(3/2) + 3, x]` return `False` since one of the  exponents is not integer.  `specialPolynomialQ` should also accept negative fractions and negative integers.

Any one knows if there exists such a function already may be in some other package?

V 13.1

Comment: Thanks to all the answer. All are great answers and I wish I can accept them both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one possibility, using an *undocumented* function:

```
specialPolynomialQ[expr_, x_] := 
With[{dtl = GroebnerBasis`DistributedTermsList[expr, x]},
     FreeQ[First[dtl], x] && 
     MatchQ[Last[dtl], {(x | (x^(_Integer | _Rational))) ..}]]
```

Some tests:

```
specialPolynomialQ[7 t^5 + 5 t^(-3/2) + 11 t^(2/3) + 3, t]
   True

specialPolynomialQ[7 t^5 + 5 t^(-3) + 2 t + 3, t]
   True

specialPolynomialQ[7 x^Pi + 5 x^(-5) + 11 x^(2/3) + 5 x + 3, x]
   False

specialPolynomialQ[7 x^2 + 5 x^(-5) + 11 x^(2/3) + 5 x + (1 - x)/(1 + x), x]
   False
```

Answer (score 3):

*I realize you are asking whether this is available in some other package. I do not know that. I will provide code instead, hope that is ok.*

Here is a solution using standard functions:

```
specialPolynomialQ[expr_,x_]:=Which[
  MatchQ[Head[expr],Plus|Times],And@@Map[specialPolynomialQ[#,x]&,List@@expr],
  MatchQ[expr,x|Power[x,_Integer|_Rational]],True,
  FreeQ[expr,x],True,
  True,False];
```

**Comment.** This defaults to `False` when it does not recognize an expression as being of the kind you describe. Therefore, it can give false negatives. In some sense also `PolynomialQ` can give false negatives:

```
PolynomialQ[(1-x^2)/(1-x),x]
(* False *)

PolynomialQ[(1-x^2)/(1-x)//Simplify,x]
(* True *)
```